# Ejabberd and MUC

Tags: ejabberd

Can't access to my conference on my server from internal jids but connection works for jids from conference domain:

test@domain.com to conference.domain.com —> works
test@internalxmppserver.com to conference.domain.com —> not works
test@domain.com to conference.internalxmppserver.com —> works

Here is my MUC config:

`%% Admins of this server are also admins of MUC service:
{access, muc_admin, [{allow, admin}]}.`

%% All users are allowed to use MUC service:
{access, muc, [{allow, all}]}.

{mod_muc,      [
                  %%{host, "conference.@HOST@"},
                  {access, all},
                  {access_create, all},
                  {access_persistent, all},
                  {access_admin, muc_admin},
                  {max_users, 500}
                 ]},

Answer (score 1):

Here are the MUC relevant bits of my ejabberd.conf for what it is worth - works for me :

```
{access, muc_admin, [{allow, admin}]}.
{access, muc, [{allow, all}]}.

{mod_muc, [{access, all},
  {access_create, all},
  {access_admin, muc_admin}]},
```

The mod_muc is of course only valid as part of the modules stanza.

Your configuration looks fine to my innocent eyes, except the *'%%{host, "conference.@HOST@"}* which puzzles me. What are you trying to do with it ? Remove it and see if it works : the default name for the conference server created with ejabbed is "conference." added to the ejabberd server's hostname.

Comment: This %%host entry isn't mine, it was default in config file. I'll try "all" settings but I've tried it yet, maybe I'll be lucky.